# Photo stitching in Flutter

Tags: flutter, photo, panoramas, image-stitching

I need to stitch several photos together and create a panorama image of that. I didn't find any package or method which can detect overlap between two images and produce a final image with no overlap.
Are there any existing libraries that could do that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this via OpenCV, OpenCV is compatible with Flutter via the [OpenCV flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/opencv). Try to find some native implementation and convert it to the dart equivalent.